# How can I make the script to work?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 HTML form inputs fields that is dynamically generated by a "add more" button, with naming for the fields name as `fieldName, fieldName1, fieldName2, fieldName3`,  and so on.

Now, I'm trying to retrieve the value from this fields with JavaScript, using the script below.

```
var bookingForm = document.forms['formName'];

var qty = bookingForm.fieldName +'i'.value;
```

with the 'i' been a generated numeric number by a for loop
when I use `alert(qty)`, it returns `NaN`, when I'm expecting the value for `fieldName1`, `fieldName2`,  and so on.

But when I use;

```
var qty = bookingForm.fieldName.value
```

I can get the value in that field but get `NaN` when I try to concatenate 1,2,3,  with the fieldName.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use brackets to access a property using a string:

```
var qty = bookingForm['fieldName' + i].value;
```

Comment: I still have issue with the script. bookingForm['fieldName' + i].value within a loop, gives undefined error. But when i try bookingForm['fieldName' + '1'].value, everything goes well as intended, what could be responsible for this?

Comment: @sality63: What kind of issue?

Comment: bookingForm['fieldName' + i].value within a loop, gives undefined error. But when i try bookingForm['fieldName' + '1'].value, everything goes well as intended, what could be responsible for this?

Comment: @sality63: The most likely reason is that your loop doesn't correspond with the number of elements that you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use code like:

```
var qty = bookingForm.fieldName +'i'.value;
```

`bookingForm.fieldName +'i'` is a string.  You have to change that string into a DOM element in order to access the `.value` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementsByName('fieldName'+i)[0].value`